# Why on Heroku, if I click on "About your application’s environment", it will say page not found?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

Example: http://foobar-192-305.heroku.com/

If I click on "About your application’s environment"

it will say:

> The page you were looking for doesn't
>   exist.
>
> You may have mistyped the address or
>   the page may have moved.

but if I run the server in development mode on my computer, it will pop down the info.  (and all files are added and committed with git, as `git status` shows everything committed.  This app is using Ruby 1.9.2, Rails 3.0.5)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The welcome page is not ment for production. so the url where the data is loaded from doesn't exist (`http://foobar-192-305.heroku.com/rails/info/properties`)

Comment: I wonder if there is some way to enable it?  Because it can be good for looking at the versions and config sometimes.

Comment: I don't think so, in production it's assumed you wouldn't have the default index.html file public like that and also it's insecure.

Comment: Yeah, it's a bit extraneous, especially in a system like Heroku where the server configuration is pretty static and well publicised.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because your application crashed.

In you console.

```
$sites/myapp heroku logs
```

Check those and it will tell you the erro. I bet it's because you forgot a gem file or some config like that.

Comment: is that the Heroky console?  How do you get to that?  If a gem is missing, then why development works?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. As I understood you should type `git push heroku` instead of `git push heroku master`. At least for me it works!

Comment: If you're on the master branch - those two commands are the same thing.